# Can i use a SSR for switching a fluorescent light?

Tags: arduino, solid-state-relay, fluorescent-lamp

Can I use a SSR for switching a fluorescent light on or off? Specifically, can the SSR last for a long time, and can it withstand a very large number of on/off switchings? I would also appreciate a sample circuit related to this, or references.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, some people use a solid-state relay (SSR) to switch a fluorescent light on and off.
"Control Fluorescent Lights with a Laser Pointer and an Arduino" (and some SSRs)[(a)](http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-Fluorescent-Lights-with-a-Laser-Pointer-an/);
"SSR to switch a·fluorescent light"[(b)](http://forums.parallax.com/showthread.php?81298-Solid-State-Relay),
etc.

Older fluorescent lights draw 5 to 10 times their long-term average current for many seconds when "striking" the bulb at first turn on. ([c](http://pewa.panasonic.com/assets/pcsd/catalog/semi_eng_caussr.pdf) [d](http://www.phidgets.com/documentation/Phidgets/3953_0_AC_SSR_Manual.pdf))
So solid-state relays that are inadequately rated for only 2 or 3 times that long-term average current will fail pretty quickly.
That may explain why many people ([e](http://www.wrcakron.com/catalog/10b_SSR_Applications.pdf) [f](http://lights.fcpages.com/mp1.htm)) say we should avoid using SSRs for fluorescent lights.

If you get a solid-state relay that is rated to handle that full striking current,
then there's no mechanical bits to wear out and the SSR should last for a long time.
For example, the manufacturer of Releco relays seems to think driving a "2 A fluorescent bulb" requires a SSR rated at 3 A. [g](http://www.clrwtr.com/PDF/RELECO/RELECO-Solid-State-Relays.pdf) [h](http://www.relaypros.com/Relay/Relay/SOLID_STATE_RELAYS_XR) [i](http://www.phidgets.com/docs/Solid_State_Relay_Primer)

A few fluorescent light ballasts have a "control" input to turn it on and off directly,
which may work better than completely connecting and disconnecting the power.([g](http://www.lutron.com/Education-Training/LCE/LightSources/Pages/Fluorescent.aspx) [h](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/technology/intelligentLighting/technology/fluorescent.html) [j](http://www.zilog.com/index.php?option=com_product&task=ref_design_detail&RefDesign=ZRD0011F868ZRD&Itemid=198))

I'm assuming you want to turn it on for a while, then turn it off for at least a few minutes, then later turn it on for a while.
"Dimming" a fluorescent light by rapidly turning it on and off many times a second is a completely different question.
(Do we have a question here on that topic, or am I mis-remembering
[How do you dim a streetlight bulb?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/how-do-you-dim-a-streetlight-bulb)
?)

You might consider some off-the-shelf gadget designed for turning on and off fluorescent lights remotely. [h](http://www.synapse-wireless.com/snap_dim-10) [i](http://www22.verizon.com/support/residential/homecontrol/home+monitoring+and+control/devices/atlas8763.htm) [j](http://www.smarthome.com/5942/Z-Wave-Wireless-Lighting-Control-Fluorescent-Light-Appliance-Module/p.aspx) [k](http://www.osh.com/eng/product/westek_outdoor_programmable_compact_fluorescent_light_control/6778377)